# VB.net console app pausing and staying open

Tags: vb.net, timer, console-application

Hey all i am trying to understand how to keep my console app open even after it gathers data and sends it off. I am converting a GUI to the console app. It has a timer that fires the sub every 20 seconds. But it doesnt seem like it works in the console app since after it fires off the sub it closes the app without waiting.

```
Dim secTimer As New System.Timers.Timer(20000)

Sub Main()
    Call copyRTDtoWS()
    AddHandler secTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerDone
    secTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Public Sub copyRTDtoWS()
    Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()
    Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    etc etc...
    Call resetTimer()
End Sub

Private Sub resetTimer()
    secTimer.Stop()
    secTimer.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub TimerDone(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    secTimer.Stop()
    Call copyRTDtoWS()
End Sub
```

What all do i need to do in order for it to act like the GUI version did?

Thanks for your time,

David

Comment: write console.readkey() to wait from console.it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DharaPPatel already wrote in his comment, console.readkey() makes the console application wait for a keystroke. Put it at the end of your Sub Main():

```
Sub Main()
    Call copyRTDtoWS()
    AddHandler secTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerDone
    secTimer.Enabled = True


    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```